# Python struct 'pack and unpack' doesn't work properly

Tags: python

I'm struggling with handling bytes with python.

I have a question about struct in python.

```
import struct

print(struct.unpack('>H', b'\x87\x65')[0])      # result : 34661
print(struct.unpack('>h', b'\x87\x65')[0])      # result : -30875
print(struct.pack('>H', 34661))                 # result : b'\x87e'
print(struct.pack('>h', -30875))                # result : b'\x87e
```

Why this happens? What does the `e` mean?

Thank you I really need your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `e` is the actual ASCII character `e`, representation of the code point `0x65` in that encoding (image shows decimal, binary, hex, and the character):

[image]

You can see this in the following Python transcript:

```
>>> print(chr(0x65))
e

>>> print(hex(ord('e')))
0x65

>>> print('\x65')
e
```

In other words, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, it is a matter of character representation.
Since you are printing ASCII-values, you should refer to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), more precisely to its 'hexadecimal' column denoted as 'Hx'. Then you will find that `0x65` stands for `e` symbol.

Please, consider using `binascii` library and its `hexlify` function for convenient output of bytes

```
import binascii
import struct

print(struct.unpack('>H', b'\x87\x65')[0])           # result : 34661
print(struct.unpack('>h', b'\x87\x65')[0])           # result : -30875
print(binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>H', 34661)))    # result : b'8765'
print(binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>h', -30875)))   # result : b'8765'
```